# Retrofit @Path sending query instead

Tags: android, retrofit, proguard, okhttp

I am using Retrofit in my project and this code to update records in a database:

```
@PATCH("/api/payments/{id}/")
Call<Payment> updatePayment(@Path("id") int id, @Body Payment payment);
```

the problem is, retrofit is supposed to send the request like this:

https://example.herokuapp.com/api/payments/4/

which is how the @Path tag should send the request

requests are sent as if the were @Query tag queries, for example:

https://example.herokuapp.com/api/payments/?id=4

What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you remove the last "/"?

Comment: I've removed it. Still getting the same result

Comment: And can you change `PATCH` to `POST`

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS Your previous comment is correct. Also, there is diff between POST & PATCH so can't be right way to change it